# Converting DoubleBinding into double in javaFX

Tags: java, javafx, double

```
DoubleBinding angle = new SimpleDoubleProperty(myIndex*Math.PI*2).divide(nrMoons);
moon.centerXProperty().bind(earth.centerXProperty().add(Math.cos(angle.doubleValue()).multiply(RADIUS_ORBIT)));
```

that is the part of my code, where I get an error that double **angle.doubleValue()** cannot be dereferenced, and Math.cos() requires a double not a DoubleBinding, any idea on how to convert it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the quantity you want to add is the product of the cosine of the angle, and `RADIUS_ORBIT`, you just need to use the operator `*` instead of the function `multiply`:

```
moon.centerXProperty().bind(earth.centerXProperty().add(Math.cos(angle.doubleValue()) * RADIUS_ORBIT));
```

Note that this probably won't work the way you want: the value you pass to `add(...)` is not observable (it's just a plain `double`), so the value will only update if `earth.centerXProperty()` changes, but won't update if `angle` changes. This is not so much because of using `*` instead of `multiply()`, but because `Math.cos()` returns a plain `double` instead of some kind of `ObservableDoubleValue`. There's no direct API in JavaFX properties/bindings for "taking the cosine of a value".

If you want this to depend dynamically on `angle`, you should use a custom binding (which also has the advantage of making the computation easier to see in the code).

I think this is the value you want to compute:

```
moon.centerXProperty.bind(Bindings.createDoubleBinding(() -> {
    double earthCenter = earth.getCenterX();
    double offset = Math.cos(angle.get()) * RADIUS_ORBIT ;
    return earthCenter + offset ;
}, earth.centerXProperty(), angle);
```